# Validating XML request body using camel

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, swagger

We want to validate incoming XML request using apache camel, if anything is passed null,or matching with regex or not. Scenario is below :

## We have a router like this :

```
    rest().description("SAMPLE REST API")
    .consumes("application/xml").produces("application/xml")
    .post("/myendpoint")
    .type(MyEndpointRequest.class)
    .description("Get My Endpoint Info")
    .param().name("header1").type(RestParamType.header).endParam()
    .param().name("header2").type(RestParamType.header).endParam()
    .outType(MyEndpointResponse.class)
    .responseMessage().code(200).endResponseMessage()
    .to("direct:myendpointImpl");


    from("direct:myendpointImpl")
    .bean(transactionIdGenerator)
    .setHeader("header3", constant("myendpointImpl"))
    .process(new HeaderValidationProcessor())
    .to("validator:customerinfo.xsd")
    .validate(header("validation").isEqualTo("success"))
    .setProperty("RequestData", simple("${body}"))
    .process(new MyEndpointTokenProcessor())
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))

    .to("{{MyEndpoint_token_url}}?proxyHost={{proxyHost}}&proxyPort={{proxyPort}}&bridgeEndpoint=true")
    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)

    .process(new AuthenticationProcessor())
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/xml"))
    .recipientList(simple("${in.header.instance_url}/services/apexrest/ABCCompanyInformation/?proxyHost={{proxyHost}}&proxyPort={{proxyPort}}&bridgeEndpoint=true&httpClient.cookiePolicy=ignoreCookies"))
    .process(new CustInfoRespProcessor())
    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .marshal().jacksonxml(true)
    .to("xslt:RemoveNode.xsl")
```

## .end();

For the swagger body, in swagger UI, we have created the bean from request XML and passed it to " .type(MyEndpointRequest.class)".
It is working fine.

Now we want to validate the input XML. For that I have searched and found some solution mentioning  : .to("validator:customerinfo.xsd") , where I have to convert the request XML into XSD file and it will start working.

I have done similer thing with JSON request using : .to("json-validator:XYZ.json") , where we have converted the request JSON into JSON schema and imported the "camel-json-validator" in POM.

Is there any way like JSON-validator.
We have also Beans for request XML, if we can reutilize the same for validation.

Answer (score 0):

XSD validation works similar manner as `json-validator`, you have to define an XSD schema and set of rules inside the XSD so your XML file will be validated against this file. You don't need to do any XML data conversion of your own

Comment: I have tried the suggested solution, but it's not working. Could you please share any useful link/blog, that will help.